# Using output from regex in another regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text document that contains the NAT rules for a firewall. I have been able to extract some elements from the document using a combination of regexes, but now I need to use the individual results of the regex in another regex to find the IP addresses -

The document is essentially a firewall policy, in text form. So my initial regex is built to return the value that is in each respective column in a NAT policy on a firewall (source, destination, translated source, translated destination). This is fine when IP addresses only, are used. However there are times in which a group name is used in one of those columns. I need to be able to extract the IP info from a group and then write it all to a file for review....for instance

"Server_Group" is the name of one source group. This is how the IPs are listed in the document:

```
:name (Server-Group)
            )
            :ip_convention_object ()
            :color (black)
            :comments ()
            :group_convention_query ()
            :group_sort_type (3)
            :is_convention_on (false)
            :member_class (network_object)
            :members_query ()
            :type (group)
            : (ReferenceObject
                :Table (network_objects)
                :Name (n-10.10.24.0_s22)
                :Uid ("{DACDEBF9-C041-4C48-928E-92E564606XXX}")
            )
            : (ReferenceObject
                :Table (network_objects)
                :Name (n-10.40.30.0_s23)
                :Uid ("{3E947D4C-CE05-45B4-AFCC-553351A7FRRRE}")
            )
            : (ReferenceObject
                :Table (network_objects)
                :Name (n-10.44.28.0_s23)
                :Uid ("{3EE3901E-7490-4FDF-A66C-CC9CCC17794}")
            )
            : (ReferenceObject
                :Table (network_objects)
                :Name (n-10.30.20.0_s22)
                :Uid ("{51ERR8DA-BFDB-42CD-8C3B-71OPP
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
import re



with open("INT-1DC-DMS-rulebases_5_0.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
source=re.findall(r':src_adtr\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)
dest=re.findall(r':dst_adtr\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)
source_adtr=re.findall(r':src_adtr_translated.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)
dest_adtr=re.findall(r':dst_adtr_translated\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s*\s+.*\s+.*\s.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text)


for i, j, k, m in source, dest, source_adtr, dest_adtr: #for each element found in each respective list, find appropriate IP addresses
    source-IP = (r':name\s+[\(]source[\)].*?[\(]ReferenceObject.*?:Name[\(](.*)', text)



with open("NA-INT-RuleNat.txt", "w") as s:
        for item in zip(source, dest, source_adtr, dest_adtr):
            s.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(*item))
```

Comment: You seem to be over-complicating this too much, can you post an example on what is your expected capture for the provided example content? As it stands now it's not clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: Sure...I would like the output (using the current example) to, upon finding ":name (sever-group)" to then return --  n-10.10.24.0_s22, n-10.40.30.0_s23, n-10.44.28.0_s23, n-10.30.20.0_s22 -- as I mentioned the first regex expression finds the item "server-group" the second regex needs to then take "server-group" and find the IP addresses contained therein.

Comment: I need to know how to use the output of the first regex - source=re.findall(r':src_adtr\s+.*\s+.*\s+:Name\s+[\(](.*)', text -- and use the items returned in another regex. As an example, the aforementioned regex will return "Server-Group" as one of its matches. I need to then parse the document for "Server-Group" and then find all the IP addresses associated with the group